# Android Volley Not Updating URL data

Tags: android

When i run URL in browser its show with updated data but with Volley request URL data not update.

```
protected void getImagesArray() {
    arrayList.clear();
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
    String url = "https://aditibendi3.000webhostapp.com/test_img/testarray.php";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    String image = jsonObject.getString("image");
                    model = new Model(image);
                    arrayList.add(model);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this, arrayList);
            gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.e(TAG, "onErrorResponse: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

This is url response

[{"id":"11","image":"11.png"},{"id":"10","image":"10.png"},{"id":"9","image":"9.png"},{"id":"8","image":"8.png"},{"id":"7","image":"7.png"},{"id":"6","image":"6.png"},{"id":"5","image":"5.png"},{"id":"4","image":"4.jpg"},{"id":"3","image":"3.png"},{"id":"2","image":"2.png"},{"id":"1","image":"1.png"}]

and this is volley response

E/MainActivity: onResponse:
 [{"id":"9","image":"9.png"},{"id":"8","image":"8.png"},{"id":"7","image":"7.png"},{"id":"6","image":"6.png"},{"id":"5","image":"5.png"},{"id":"4","image":"4.jpg"},{"id":"3","image":"3.png"},{"id":"2","image":"2.png"},{"id":"1","image":"1.png"}]

**I have solved this issue by using this line 
AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url);**

Comment: volley returning the same records as returned by URL no difference between Volley and URL

Comment: no volley not returning same url. if you check it right now then it may be same because you hit the url first time. if i update data from server then volley not update.

Comment: check the screenshot http://prntscr.com/g87um1

Comment: add one more record

Comment: added check now

Comment: yes I'm facing the issue very strange and wired

Comment: sure I'll look into it and let you know

Comment: did you face this issue on Mobile Phone?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151871/discussion-between-akp-and-akhilesh-patil).